# Lambda Calculus: Why is the second equation more general than the first?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I was reading up on lambda calculus from ***Introduction to Lambda Calculus*** by
Henk Barendregt and Erik Barendsen and came across this:

$(λ~x.f[\textbf{x}])\textbf{x} = f[\textbf{x}]$
more generally one has
$(λ~x.f[\textbf{x}])\textbf{N} = f[\textbf{N}]$

Why is the second equation more general than the first?

Comment: Perhaps $x$ is a single variable while $N$ represents an arbitrary term? It would be helpful if you mentioned the number of the page where you found this so that we could see the context.

Comment: It's on page 8.

Comment: You're new, so you simply don't know... but I hope you can learn:  This is a *terrible* title, which barely refers to the content of your question.  (Is this about topology?  Differential equations? 
 Complex analytic sheaf cohomology?  Oh... and "latter" *what*??) Change it.

Comment: I am sorry about the title. I will change it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess in the comment seems to be correct: In

$$(λ\vec x.f[\vec x])\vec x = f[\vec x]$$

the λ-expression is being applied to   a list of variables $\vec x$, but in

$$(λ\vec x.f[\vec x])\vec N = f[\vec N]$$

it is being applied to a list of arbitrary terms $\vec N$.

A single variable is the simplest possible special case of a term, as explained in definition 2.1 on page 9.

Comment: Thank you. I think I get it now.

Comment: So while x is a list of variables, N is a list of expressions?

Comment: Yes, if you understand "expression" in the special limited sense of definition 2.1.